# Informix Database table update

Tags: database, informix

We have 230 million records in informix database table, we partitioned table into 4 parts, but still is taking around 80 seconds to insert/update 2000 records,could somebody suggest better idea to reduce time to less then 20 seconds?

Comment: Is the indexing optimized for the operation(s) you are seeking?

Comment: yes , is there any temp table or caching technique works for this ?

Comment: There's remarkably little information in this question.  230 million records is a substantial number, but how wide are the rows?  Is each row 4 bytes, or 400 bytes, or 4000 bytes?  What is the nature of the update you are doing?  Are you making the DBMS perform complex calculations on each row?  Are you updating key columns (those which are part of the primary or foreign keys)?  Are you updating indexed columns?  Are you running a single UPDATE statement, or are you using UPDATE … WHERE CURRENT OF _cursor_name_ and making the system send each row to the client and back to the server?

Comment: Are you doing a searched update each time, instead of the previous alternatives?  Is the update being driven from the same machine as the server, or are they separate?  How separate (round trip message time)?  What else is going on while the UPDATE is running?   How are your transactions structured?  How much logical log have you got?  How is the server configured in general?  What sorts of disks are you using?  You mention partitioned into 4 parts — what does that mean in practice? Which version of Informix are you using, and which o/s are you using it on? Some or all of this may be a factor.

Comment: as well as Jonathans questions, you said "insert/update", what is the ratio of inserts to updates? and what do you try first, insert or update?, and have you compared performance "insert if duplicate update" versus "update if no rows updated insert".

Answer (score 0):

Using a cursor might speed things up a lot. But keep in mind before flush or close the rows might not be available for "drity read".
I don't know what kind of language you are using so i choose 4js genero for example.

```
PREPARE p FROM "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(?, ?, ?)"
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR p
OPEN c
WHILE (...there's more data to process...)

    PUT c USING v1, v2, v3
END WHILE
CLOSE c
```

Answer (score 0):

SET PDQ PRIORITY could be one. Also, updating statistics (high) after creating (the right) indexes can help a lot.